# Como obtener valores repetidos de Nodos un xml C#

Tags: c#, xml

quiero obtener los valores de cada nodo, tengo los primeros valores puedo verlos separados el problema biene en la parte de nodo hijo "ContainerType" que no se como entrar o recorrerlo.

necesito tambien obtener los valores de ese nodo de los 2 contenedores,asi como la imagen que tambien aparesca su info de cada uno del nodo "ContainerType"

mi xml:

```
    <DocumentedChargeable>33.000</DocumentedChargeable>
    <DocumentedVolume>111.000</DocumentedVolume>
    <DocumentedWeight>33.000</DocumentedWeight>
    <NoOfPacks>10</NoOfPacks>
    <ContainerNumber>CONTAINER 1</ContainerNumber>

    <ContainerType>
      <Code>20FR</Code>

      <Category>
        <Code>FLT</Code>
        <Description>Flat Rack</Description>
      </Category>

      <Description>Twenty foot flatrack</Description>
      <ISOCode>22P1</ISOCode>

      <GoodsDescription>
        <SKU>21-1092303</SKU>
        <Description>Descripcion de la Mercancia del Conteiner 1</Description>
      </GoodsDescription>

    </ContainerType>
    <DocumentedChargeable>X33.000</DocumentedChargeable>
    <DocumentedVolume>X111.000</DocumentedVolume>
    <DocumentedWeight>X33.000</DocumentedWeight>
    <NoOfPacks>X10</NoOfPacks>
    <ContainerNumber>XCONTAINER 2</ContainerNumber>

    <ContainerType>
      <Code>20FRX</Code>

      <Category>
        <Code>FLTX</Code>
        <Description>Flat RackX</Description>
      </Category>

      <Description>Twenty foot flatrackX</Description>
      <ISOCode>22P1X</ISOCode>

      <GoodsDescription>
        <SKU>21-10945432X</SKU>
        <Description>XMercancia del Conteiner 2</Description>
        <SKU>21-10955441X</SKU>
        <Description>XMercancia del Conteiner 2</Description>
      </GoodsDescription>
      </ContainerType>
```

```
mi codigo que uso paara obtener los valores debajo del nodo containerlist:

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"C:\test\miarchivo.xml");
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DocumentedChargeable");
            XmlNodeList elemList2 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DocumentedVolume");
            XmlNodeList elemList3 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DocumentedWeight");
            XmlNodeList elemList4 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("NoOfPacks");
            XmlNodeList elemList5 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ContainerNumber");


            for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("DocumentedChargeable: " + elemList[i].InnerXml);
               Console.WriteLine("DocumentedVolume: " + elemList2[i].InnerXml);
                Console.WriteLine("DocumentedWeight: " + elemList3[i].InnerXml);
                Console.WriteLine("NoOfPacks: " + elemList4[i].InnerXml);
                Console.WriteLine("ContainerNumber: " + elemList5[i].InnerXml);
               Console.WriteLine("=========================================");
            }
```

este es el resultado que obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito obtener los valores del nodo "ContainerType" para que se unan a los datos arrojados de la imagen anterior,quiero mostrar todos los vslores de cada nodo y de los 2 "ContainerType "  para llegar a este resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguro es algo sencillo,pero ya estoy confundido..
Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo porque se complica tanto? Porque no lee los datos de los xml y los mete en una tabla en una base de datos y desde allí entonces hace todas las operaciones que necesite?

Comment: soy algo nuevo en esto de xml,me podria orientar potfavor?

Comment: Todos los xml tienen la misma estructura???

Comment: Es decir los mismos nodos o a veces tienen más o menos nodos?

Comment: Primero paseme la estructura exacta de los xml para ver si le ayudo. Pero investigue bien si esa estructura a veces cambia y que provoca esos cambios.

Comment: Si, esos nodos son todos los que se manejan

Comment: esta es la estructura completa:
https://pastebin.com/uGtLQDkk

Comment: tiene skype usted? Agregueme al skype : richviquez@hotmail.com. O busqueme en facebook arsoftcr@gmail.com

Comment: ya te mande skype